# Create simple redirect rule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Trying to figure out how to redirect subdirectory including directories to specific subdirectory, ie.

- domain.com/something
- domain.com/something/anythingelse

to

- domain.com/newfolder

but can't figure out the correct rule... Now I have

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/something[/](.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /newfolder [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where did you put those rules? Are they in an htaccess file that has other rules in it?

Comment: yes, .htaccess, there is some wordpress stuff in there...

Comment: Did you put your rules before your wordpress rules?

Comment: yes, the rule does work for domain.com/something, but doesn't for domain.com/something/anythingelse

Comment: are there any more htaccess files? any in the `something` folder?

Comment: no extra .htaccess files..

Comment: Try only with this rule: `RewriteRule ^something /newfolder [R=301,L]`

Comment: No luck, that redirects `domain.com/something/anythingelse` to `domain.com/newfolder/anythingelse`

Comment: That's not supposed to, have you cleared your browser's cache?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/something/
RewriteRule (.*) /newfolder [R=301,L]`